# CSS animation 'transform' issue

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I've encountered an issue I can't seem to solve on my own. I am trying to drift three divs ( 2 from left to right & 1 from right to left ) using the 'transform' function. Basically I want to create 3 "boxes" that drift in from the outside of the page and then stop at a certain point. The function works, but when I add the third div while it is sliding in from the right an expanding bottom scroll bar shows up.
Why am I getting that scroll-bar? If I inspect the page there is a margin border that shouldn't be there, but my body margin is set to 0. This also only happens when I add the third div. This confuses me. Would be great if you could check it out and let me know what's wrong here. I'm guessing the issue is with div3? Also, is this the correct way to do it or is there a "better" way in terms of the function used(transform). Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


.introbox-one {
  width: 70%;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: introbox-one 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes introbox-one {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.introbox-two {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: introbox-two 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes introbox-two {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.introbox-three {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: introbox-three 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes introbox-three {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="introbox-one"></div>

    <div class="introbox-two"></div>

    <div class="introbox-three"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the third `div` element is overflowing, by default it allows you to scroll. This behaviour can be changed using the [overflow-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) property and setting it to `hidden` prevents the scrolling. We'll add this to the parent element, which in this case is the body.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


.introbox-one {
  width: 70%;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: introbox-one 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes introbox-one {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.introbox-two {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: introbox-two 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes introbox-two {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.introbox-three {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: introbox-three 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes introbox-three {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="introbox-one"></div>

    <div class="introbox-two"></div>

    <div class="introbox-three"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

**PS:** The horizontal scrollbar appears because by transforming the divs you are making them bigger than the container, creating an **overflow**, it is elements' default behaviour that a scrollbar pops up to allow the user to - by means of scrolling - view the content that is overflown. You can override this behaviour by setting the container elements 'overflow-x' (for horizontal overflow) and 'overflow-y' (for vertical overflow) to 'hidden'; this will disable the scrollbar popping up and the overflown portion of the content will never be visible.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.introbox {
  width: 70%;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: introbox-one 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes introbox-one {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

.introbox-three {
 margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="introbox introbox-one"></div>

    <div class="introbox introbox-two"></div>

    <div class="introbox introbox-three"></div>
  </body>
```